# Get a page behind autentication via Fetch/XMLHttpRequest in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, fetch

I need to add to the [cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) a page that is behind authentication.
The authentication is made with Devise gem and can use the email or the google oauth.
I need to cache this page only when the user has **already been authenticated** with the normal form.

But if I use:
`fetch('books/page-behind-authentication')` after the user has been authenticated the response is the `auth/login` page to which I've been redirected to.

How can I do to retrieve the page behind authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetch('books/page-behind-authentication', {
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```

Is the way to do this. This will add your credentials (HTTP cookies, TLS client certificates, and authentication entries) to the request so you can have a correct response